# Gradle - set specific JAVA_HOME for a specific project

Tags: gradle, javac

Due to different servers running different JVM version.  I would like to set a specific project to specific JDK version.  I'm thinking may be setting JAVA_HOME with a task which compilation depends on it, but I'm not sure how to code it yet.  But then there may be a simple setting I can do in build.gradle for that!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after `sourceCompatibility`and `targetCompatibility`. Settings those on a project has - as far as compilation is concerned - the same effect than `-source` and `-target` parameters to `javac`. If you need different settings for different compile tasks in one project, even that would be possible.

Comment: Thanks Vampire.  But I got a warning ":compileJava warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6", wonder if I can do more!?  Can you provide example about different compile tasks in one project?  Much appreciated.

Comment: You can simply set the same properties on a JavaCompile task. They just default to the ones set on the project that contains the task. The warning is the same as if you call `javac` with an older `-source` or `-target`. It means you could use some classes or methods that are different in 1.8 regarding to 1.6 you compile for and it would compile, but fail at runtime. Java cannot know all APIs of all older versions. You can set the bootstrap classpath for the compile task to a JRE that fits your `-source` setting and the warning will go away.